# Build Trigger Doesn't Work on New Release

Tags: azure-devops

I want Azure DevOps to kick off a build pipeline when a new release is created in GitHub whether it's a pre-release or full release. I have the following at the top of my yaml:

```
trigger:
 - releases/*
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#triggers), that's all I should need and it's very similar to how I was doing it in TeamCity.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#triggering-a-pipeline) you can only have triggers on the following events:

1. A change is pushed to GitHub repo (CI trigger)
2. A pull request is created or updated (PR trigger)
3. A special command is typed in pull request comments (Comment trigger)

so your example is simply triggering on a push to a **branch** called `release/*`. I dont think what you are trying to achieve is possible.

Comment: My train of thought was that GitHub considers releases a branch, thus creating a release would essentially be the same as #1 above. It looks like I'll have to include `- master` and race DevOps on creating the release before the build kicks off. :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after the fact.

```
# Trigger a build on new releases
trigger:
  tags:
    include: [ v* ] # Assuming releases/tags are prefixed with v. Edit as needed.
```

[YAML schema reference - Triggers - Push Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#push-trigger)